# "Предложение о сотрудничестве" или "Предложение сотрудничества"

Tags: фразеология

В общем, на работе получил "болванку" КП с темой письма "предложение о сотрудничестве", недолго думал и поменял на "предложение сотрудничества". И начал рассылать клиентам такие КП. Потом "погуглил" и осознал, что никто кроме меня таким заголовком не пользуется. С моей точки зрения, предложение о сотрудничестве - это одно предложение - с подлежащим, со сказуемым, и чем-то про сотрудничество. 
И так как моё предложение - это действие (я предлагаю), направленное на оппонента, и предлагаю я ему сотрудничество, собственно, предложение должно быть чего-то, а не о чем-то.

Полагаю, что "предложение о сотрудничестве" нужно принять как данность и успокоиться 8) Есть ли у кого-то авторитетное мнение на этот счет?

Answer (score 1):

> Это *предложение сотрудничества*? А какая зарплата?.. Сэкономить
>   деньги за счет более выгодного *предложения сотрудничества* в вопросах
>   перевода... Принято большинством сограждан как предложение
>   сотрудничества...

Как видно, такое словосочетание в большей мере уместно для неформального изложения новостей, сведений, прогнозов в публикациях, переписке, общении.

То, что предлагается «принять за данность», является фиксированной в терминах деловой традиции и документооборота фразой, стандартным наименованием документа о намерениях:

> внутренняя база *предложений о сотрудничестве*; ответ на письмо с
>   *предложением о сотрудничестве* может быть положительным; невыгодное для
>   последнего *предложение о сотрудничестве*.

Итого: в названии письма уместна форма *предложение о сотрудничестве*, в тексте (всё того же письма) — *предложение сотрудничества* или его развития.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот тоже задался таким вопросом и мне тоже ближе "предложение сотрудничества", но погуглив образцы, в основном пишут "предложение о сотрудничестве", придется смириться))